# Derive additional accounts from private key

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, private-key, ethereumjs

Im building a dApp and during account creation I can generate an address as well as private/public (extended) keys.

What i want is to be able to generate further accounts after the seed is no longer available, the only object available to the user is web3 secret storage from which i can get the users private key, if I am not mistaken the only time i can get the extended private key is during the account creation or when the user supplies their seed.

Is it not possible to create further derived addresses from a private key ?